# How could I rewrite this set of routes more cleanly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I feel like I should know this and I'm certain this could be done more cleanly, but I'm not quite sure the best way to go about it.

How could a set of routes like this be written in a more DRY way?

```
# Artists
match "/:id/remixes", :to => "artists#remixes", :as => "artist_remixes"
match "/:id/originals", :to => "artists#originals", :as => "artist_originals"
match "/:id/popular", :to => "artists#popular", :as => "artist_popular"
match "/:id/mashups", :to => "artists#mashups", :as => "artist_mashups"
match "/:id/covers", :to => "artists#covers", :as => "artist_covers"
match "/:id/productions", :to => "artists#productions", :as => "artist_productions"
match "/:id/features", :to => "artists#features", :as => "artist_features"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it:

```
resources :artists, path: '/' do
  member do
    get 'remixes'
    get 'originals'
    get 'popular'
    get 'mashups'
    get 'covers'
    get 'features'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thats it!  The path:'/' part was what I needed.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading, my paths were flipped (which makes sense) to be 'remixes_artist', 'originals_artist', etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would look to try and do 1 route and pass list_type as a parameter.

Something like

```
resources: artists do
  resources list_types
end
```

I would try and avoid having seperate actions for a bunch of methods that probably do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, should have just thought this through (hungover today):

```
[:remixes_of, :remixes_by, :originals, :popular, :mashups, :covers, :productions, :features].each do |role|
  match ":id/#{role}", to: "artists\##{role}", as: "artist_#{role}"
end
```

Comment: Although this is more compact, it's not declarative or readable.